# what is the equivalent in Java for the fmShareDenyNone FileOpen statement in Delphi?

Tags: java, delphi

Could you help to comment what is the equivalent in Java for the following fmShareDenyNone FileOpen statement in Delphi?

```
TFileStream.Create(
    'C:\Test.txt', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
```

, where `fmShareDenyNone` is used in the FileOpen call together with one of fmOpenReadWrite, fmOpenRead or fmOpenWrite, to open a file so other processes can read/write the file as well.

Currently I am using the following statement to Open a file for Write. It gives "java.nio.file.FileSystemException: ... the file because it is being used by another process." if I opened a second file viewer such as UltraEdit.

```
BufferedWriter br = java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedWriter(
    java.nio.file.Paths.get("test.txt"), 
    java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("UTF-8"), 
    new java.nio.file.OpenOption[]{java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.WRITE}
);
```

PS: I am hoping a built-in equivalent(which is naturally cross-platform).

Many thanks for your opinions!

Comment: @David: No, I want to open the same text file in notepad, write and eclipse.

Comment: Why using java.nio? java.io has a lot of reader and writer absolutely not exclusive.